# UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification not calling

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I am using below code for detecting whem my viewcontroller shows from background:

```
    - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
// some other codes
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(backsFromBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:self];

}
```

and:

```
    - (void) backsFromBackground:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    //Do something

}
```

and:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:self];

}
```

but the observer not calling and the method backsFromBackground: not calling. Does some one has any idea?

Comment: Try removing `self` from `object` portion of notification. Set it to `nil`.

Comment: worked, what was the problem? can you especify?

Comment: Please check my post now. I've given the explanation there. Glad it helped :)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this out: notificationSender must be `nil` in your case.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // some other codes
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(backsFromBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}
```

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver:selector:name:object:): last parameter is your `notificationSender`:

> The object whose notifications the observer wants to receive; that is,
>   only notifications sent by this sender are delivered to the observer.
>
> If you pass nil, the notification center doesn’t use a notification’s
>   sender to decide whether to deliver it to the observer.

Comment: Very thanks, +1 because of good reference to apple document and accept because of your help ;)

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
  selector:@selector(backsFromBackground:)
  name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
  object:self];
```

to

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
  selector:@selector(backsFromBackground:)
  name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
  object:nil];
```

The last `object` parameter in the `NSNotificationCenter` subscription is the notification sender, the object you want to observe from. The changes aren't coming from your view controller (`self`), they come from `UIApplication`.

You could pass in `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`, but because there's only one instance of `UIApplication` you can leave the `object` parameter as nil.

You will want to do the same in your `removeObserver` code too.

Comment: thanks for detailed description. Only one answer can accept. So I accepted Abhinav answer because he posted soon. But +1 and very thanks because of detailed answer and your help.

Comment: I had already solutionized this. Please check comments to OP's question :).

Comment: @Abhinav there was only one answer so it's not like I had to copy ;)